# My \d[A-Z]\d regex doesn't work

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I'm trying to match numbers like 3X3464 5J3454

but the following code isn't doing it for me.

```
If RegExmatch(A_LoopReadLine,"\d[A-Z]\d\d\d\d\")
```

What simple thing do I not know about regex?

Comment: Seems like the closing quote is escaped (`\"`) when it shouldn't be. Is that in your actual code?

Comment: Do double quotes end up interpreting backslash as something magical? You nee the string to contain a backslash and a `d`, which might end up as something else as `\n` is a newline, etc.

Comment: yeh that's actual code - the " wasn't supposed to be escaped.

Comment: You need to post more code.  What is A_LoopReadLine?  Your code will match the inputs you gave, assuming A_LoopReadLine contains them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exact matching will be:

```
\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{4}
```

and as {1} not needed:

```
\d[A-Z]\d{4}
```

Comment: I'm sorry i misread your comment, i thought you were talking about multiple matches ({2},{3}...) , of course {1} is completely redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Rgex isn't always consistently read. Different softwares interpret regex different ways. Maybe try:

```
[0-9][A-Z][0-9]{4}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what regex variety is supported by AutoHotkey, but this works in RegEx Buddy's default variety to match both number sets in the string you posted:

```
\d[A-Z]\d{4}\b
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Ahk Code

matches:
\d -> digit character
\D -> non digit character
\d{4} == \d\d\d\d

```
FoundPos := RegExMatch("3X1234", "\d\D\d{4}") 
msgbox,%FoundPos%
```

[Autohotkey RegEx](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm)

Comment: thought I couldn't use \D because it must match an alpha character. No matching of underscores or dashes or other symbols.